# Implement IEnumerable for a collection class?

Tags: c#, foreach, enumerable, enumerator

I want to understand this topic and not just be able to throw down the syntax.  I have a collection class called IGroupNode, which can take in a maximum of 8 children ISceneNodes.

```
internal class GroupNode : IGroupNode
{
    public string Name
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    const int NumberOfChildren = 8;
    #region Member variables
    private IList<ISceneNode> children = new List<ISceneNode>(NumberOfChildren);
    #endregion

    public IEnumerable<ISceneNode> GetEnumerator()
    {
        //?
    }
```

As you can probably tell, it is a very simple collection class based off of a list.  How can I make the implementation of IEnumerable here simply return the 
internal container’s enumerator?  I am not sure how to do this in this very easy case.

Now I am running into trouble with this problem:

```
'Weber.SceneGraphCore.GroupNode' does not implement interface member 'System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()'. 'Weber.SceneGraphCore.GroupNode.GetEnumerator()' cannot implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()' because it does not have the matching return type of 'System.Collections.IEnumerator'.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply return `children.GetEnumerator()` in this case. (By the way your GroupNode object should implement IEnumerable and your GetEnumerator method should have the correct return type.)

```
public IEnumerator<ISceneNode> GetEnumerator()
{
    return children.GetEnumerator()
}
```

In more general cases though you can iterate over something and call `yield return` for each element.

Comment: Cannot implicitly define IEnumerable as IEnumerator

Comment: Did you fix the return type of GetEnumerator to IEnumerator?

Comment: No, but then how does that work.  So, the class implements IEnumerable, but in the actual implementation, I implement IEnumerator?  Why does that work..

Comment: You were correct, I just hope that IEnumerable is implemented fully now.  I will try to continue and see if I run into any problems (thank goodness for the Intellisense)

Comment: "In the actual implemenation I implement IEnumerator" This isn't accurate. Read the documentation of the interface IEnumerable. Notice the return types on the methods. Of course interface A can have a method that returns an object of type B.

Answer (score 2):

Since IList already implements `IEnumerable<>`, you can just return `children.GetEnumerator()` in your `GetEnumerator()` method.